# Cannot build gatsby project after upgrading. Module not found

Tags: reactjs, build, gatsby, react-typescript

After upgrading gastby, and react on our project, I been trying to run `gastby build` and `gastby develop` with no success. The error shown during the build is strange since it does not show on which file the error is occurring.
When running `gastby build` I'm getting several errors like the following.

```
failed Compiling Gatsby Functions - 18.617s                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Failed to validate error [Error [ValidationError]: "error" must be of type object] {                                                                                                                                                           
  _original: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    context: {},                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    error: [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './AuthProvider' in '/home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components'                                                                                     
          at /home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2022:28
          at /home/user/projects/web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:817:13
      ...
      resolve './AuthProvider' in '/home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components'
        using description file: /home/user/projects/web-app/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Auth/components)
          using description file: /home/user/projects/web-app/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider)
            no extension
              /home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider doesn't exist
            .ts
              /home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              /home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider.js doesn't exist
            .json
              /home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider.json doesn't exist
            .wasm
              /home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider.wasm doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider doesn't exist,
```

When running `gatsby develop` I get a completely different error.

```
 ERROR  UNKNOWN

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)



  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
  (Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Our project uses .tsx or .ts files. We do use some binary libraries, and for those we have set `use: loaders.null()` on the webpack config.

Just for reference, I have upgraded gatsby from 2.31.1 to 5.13.0, and react from 16.14.0 to 18.2.0.

I have tried creating a blank project and copy-pasting a page from my project into it, but the same error occurs after running `gatsby build`.
Also, the project does compile correctly using `tsc`.

Comment: Can you confirm that a file like `/home/user/projects/web-app/src/components/Auth/components/AuthProvider` exists? As you can see in the first error message it's looking for this file with various extensions. The path looks somewhat suspect with the double occurrence of `components`.